# How do languages that support operators as first class citizens abide by order of operations?

Tags: functional-programming, programming-languages

In programming languages such as F# in which infix operators are 'functions' or first class citizens, how do they abide by the order of operations such as 2 * 4 + 6 (which evaluates as (2 * 4) + 6)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Haskell, you can [specify the precedence level](https://wiki.haskell.org/Keywords#infix.2C_infixl.2C_infixr) and associativity for an operator. Scala bases the precedence on the [first character of the operator](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#infix-operations), and the associativity on the last character. I don't know F#, but it looks like it is also based on [the characters used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/operator-overloading).

Some other languages only let you overload an existing operator, not create your own, so they retain the precedence and associativity of their built-in counterparts.